Outlook rules not applied on all messages
I am part of a team (joined recently) at my company that runs a weekly meeting sent to 2000 participants. What is nonsensical right now is that when these participants respond with (Accepted, tentative, or declined), their responses are sent to our inbox. This is annoying because it fills the inbox with emails that do not have any value, so I created a rule to delete these messages. The issue is that this rule was applied to only 5000+ of them and left out 5000+.
This is how it looks like:

Do you know why it is ignoring the messages that fall under the rule?

In the smallish screenshot I can see an and, so your rule has the problem that
the "trigger words" MUST be in both Subject AND Message Header.
Change the and to an or (or the rule to be TWO separate rules)
and you will see more messages be affected.

Thank you for the reply :) The issue is that I cannot change the logic. I did think that 'and' is the issue and that it should be 'or,' but I do not know how I can change that. The only thing I can do is to choose the rules. Do you have a way to change the logic?

I do not have access to Outlook right now, so cannot verify this: The very same place where you set up filtering also allows to double click(?) on one of those you already have, and walk through it in the same way as when setting up initially.

The easy way might be to use two separate rules, doing the same "move" of the message(s)

Thank you :)  I created multiple separate rules, and that solved the issue :)

One of the "driving forces" of superuser - and all the sibling stack exchange sites - is votes, please vote and mark answer as your choice if that is what it is.
